# Reductions from 3-SAT that won't work directly from SAT

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np, satisfiability

Our prof talked about why it's good to know that 3-SAT is NP-complete because it's easier to craft reductions from it than from plain SAT.

However, all the examples we've seen (reduction to independent set, Hamiltonian cycle, etc.) seem to work even if we start from a SAT formula and not 3-SAT.

**Is there an example of a reduction technique 3-SAT$\le_p A$ to show that $A$ is NP-hard that doesn't work for SAT?**

---

I'm aware that we can always ``compound'' the $SAT\le_p$3-$SAT$ reduction with 3-$SAT\le_p A$ to get a reduction from $SAT$ to $A$.
I'm asking if there's an example where such a reduction is less "intuitive" or significantly more complex, because the ones I've seen seem to work directly (without reducing each clause to three literals.)